# Dictionary is not accessed in template page in django

Tags: python, django

I am new to Django. I am trying to pass one dictionary to my template view page but when I try to print the dictionary value using a for loop it does not print.

[image]
My folder structure is:
**mytest**

```
   -mytest
   -personal
      -templates
         -personal
         -includes
         -basic.html
         -header.html
         -home.html     
      -urls.py
      -views.py  
   -webapp
```

**view.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    return render(request,'personal/home.html')

def contact(request):
    return render(request,'personal/basic.html',{'contents':['if you like to contact me, please email me','ansarijuned@gmail.com']})
```

**basic.html**

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}
{% block content %}

    <p>This is My Home page with Header</p>

    <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2>Contact Us</h2>
            <hr />
            <% for obj in contents %>
                <p>{{ obj }}</p>
            <% endfor %>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div> 

{% include "personal/includes/headerwidget.html" %}
{% endblock %}
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
   url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
   url(r'^contact/', views.contact, name='contact'),
]
```

Comment: What is `c` in the template?

Comment: What is `{{ c }}` ?? replace it with `{{ obj }}` then you will get what you are passing in dictionary

Comment: sorry i have to use 'obj' instead of 'c' i have correct this but still no output my page is running perfectly but this loop doesnot print anything now you can see my modified code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your template you are trying to access a `{{c}}` object which does not exist. Your data is in `{{obj}}` and you can access it this way :

```
{% for obj in contents %}
 {{ obj }}
{% endfor %}
```

Then if you want to test whether your `obj` is equal to `hi` you can do :

```
{% for obj in contents %}
 {% if obj == "hi" %}
  {{ obj }}
 {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: sorry i have to use 'obj' instead of 'c' i have correct this but still no output my page is running perfectly but this loop doesnot print anything now you can see my modified  code

Comment: Can you try with `{% %}` instead of `<% %>` in your loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your template

```
<% for obj in contents %>
    <p>{{ c }}</p>
    <% if(obj== 'hi') %>
        {{c}}
    <% endif %>
<% endfor %>
```

with

```
<% for obj in contents %>
    <p>{{ obj }}</p>
    <% if(obj== 'hi') %>
        {{obj}}
    <% endif %>
<% endfor %>
```

then you will get what you are passing in dictionary.